# Upload file ftp using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload, ftp

I use code :
http://www.codexworld.com/codeigniter-upload-file-to-remote-server/

I found an error

```
Unable to upload the specified file. Please check your path.
```

my ftp path : /public_html/assets/

why the path was not found?

Comment: I guess you should check your credentials to this path. Because web-server is run under 'www' user

Comment: $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/'; This is relative to the root folder, so you do not need public_html

Comment: This code can not find the file location: $destination = '/assets/'.$fileName;

Comment: this is going to be easier if you do list files first. that way you can confirm the ftp is working and the file path is correct. once you get that working then try uploads. $list = $this->ftp->list_files('/assets/');
print_r($list); also read through the manual http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/ftp.html